# geocoder not working for iOS in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So I have an iOS problem.

I have a method that is supposed to get the location from an address. I use the geocoder method from xamarin.forms.maps, and it works fine on android, it gives me the correct location, does what it is supposed to do, but on iOS it is not working.

for some reason, after i run this line of code:

```
var geoPositions = await geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(tuple.address);
```

the rest of the code in the method does not execute, it just skips to the end of the method and doesn't do anything else. 
i don't get an error or an exception or anything, it just exits the method and continue doing other stuff. 
I have tried to use different addresses to see if that was the problem, but the same same thing happened, and it also happened when i tried to use the GetAddressForPositionAsync method with coordinates.

I am using a real device to test the app, an iPhone 6 with iOS version 11.2.6, and yes, I have added all required permissions in info.plist

Any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please can you provided the version of iOS , is real device or Simulator ?

Comment: Have you add additional keys in `info.plist`?   Refer to :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map#Platform_Configuration

Comment: I am using a real device yes, an iPhone 6 with iOS version 11.2.6, and yes, I have added all required permissions in info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem.
Apparently I was getting an exception that I for some reason couldn't see.

System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init (); prior to using it. at Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync.

Once I noticed that, I saw that

Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init ();

had only been added to the main activity in android, and not in iOS. 
I added that, and now it is working correctly.